# ios Picker View with text field

Tags: ios, xcode

i tried to join textfield with Picker view when someone clicks on that text field, instead of bringing up the default keyboard, I want it to bring up a Picker View which lists several choices of my liking.

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface activate : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *gender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *arrStatus;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *GenderTextField;

@end
```

.m file contain

```
@synthesize gender;
@synthesize arrStatus;
@synthesize GenderTextField;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.GenderTextField.inputView = gender;
    arrStatus = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Male", @"Female", nil];
}
-(void)textFieldBeganEditing:(NSNotification *)note{
    GenderTextField = note.object; // set ivar to current first responder
    [gender setHidden:NO];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    //One column
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    //set number of rows
    return arrStatus.count;
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    //set item per row
    return [arrStatus objectAtIndex:row];
}
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    self.GenderTextField.text=[arrStatus objectAtIndex:row];


}
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.GenderTextField.inputView = self.gender;
    [gender setHidden:NO];

}
```

any help or example will be apprciated

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

I think one easy way is to add a transparent button above your `UITextField`. Don't let user click that text field. When user click your text field you can show your picker. After user finish picking. Update your text field.

Answer (score 0):

the trick is to never let the textfield becomeFirstResponder

subclass the Field and instead of passing touches to super which would call becomeFirstResponder, show the picker view

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way, implement UITextfieldDelegate protocol. THere is a method named

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextfield *)textfield
```

You may do something on this method then

```
return NO;
```

keyboard will not be shown anymore

Code will look like following

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextfield *)textfield
{
      //Do somethings....


      return NO;
}
```